# How to put a div inside a textbox

Tags: jquery, css, html

Part of asking a question on SO is typing tags.  When you type a tag and click it, a div goes into the textbox.  (at least that's what i think is happening).  How can i put a div inside a textbox like that? Currently I can only change the value of the textbox to the dropdown item using this:

JQUERY:

```
$('.item_display').click(function(){
$('#Result').css("display" , "none");
var item = $(this).text();

$('#userInput').val(item);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='userInput' autocomplete='off' /> 
<div id='Results'></div>  //this is the dropdown menu where .item_display appears
```

Comment: Take a look at the Chosen plugin. What really happens is there is a container div that LOOKS like a text box with a textbox aligned left. As you add items, you are adding another element to the left of the textbox and it slides over. http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: It's not a text-box, it's just a `<div>` styled to look like a text-box.

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome Console to inspect it, it's not what you think.

Comment: FYI: [This](http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/tageditornew.js) appears to be the (compressed) source.

Comment: Compressed source is not much use.

Comment: @Splash-X thanks but i prefer to write my own code. there must be a simple way to do this without that plugin

Comment: the simple way is to use the plugin and not reinvent bugs

Comment: @icktoofay, [cleaned version](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7aKLgsUd)... not that it's much use outside of SE.  (And I doubt even more it's legal to use.)

Comment: @Valamas: I beg to differ. You can use http://www.jsbeautifier.org/ or the like to re-indent it and then you can see the general flow of how it does things.

Comment: @kirby If you don't want to use a plugin that already exists download the plugin anyways, study how they create their control and model yours after it. I agree with Michael Durrant, don't reinvent the wheel and work out all of the bugs. All things considered, we've given you working examples to model your code after should you wish to create your own, what more could you want than a real working example?

Comment: @Splash-X ok.  good point. can you make your comment an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin Chosen is a good example of how to do this. The idea is what appears to be a text box really isn't. A container DIV spans the width of your desired element. A textbox sits to the left and spans the width of your area. As you type and add elements, new divs appear to the left of the textbox pushing the textbox right and re-scaling the width. There probably are may implementations of this in various plugins but I've worked with Chosen,

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/